# When a select box option is selected do something, else do something else using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the code below:

```js
$("#dropdowncities").change(function () {
if ($('#dropdowncities option:selected').val()) {
    $(".filter-dot").removeClass("hide");
    $(".filter-dot").addClass("show");
} else {
    $(".filter-dot").removeClass('show');
    $(".filter-dot").addClass("hide");
}
});
```

```css
.filter-dot {
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background:red;
    border-radius:50%; 
}

.show {display:block;}

.hide {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="filter-dot hide"></div>

<select id="dropdowncities">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option>This is an option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
</select>
```

I want to make it so if select box has any option, then the "filter-dot" element must be displayed and when select box has no option selected then the "filter-dot" element must be hidden.

Comment: Isn't that what your code already does?

Comment: FYI, you can just write `$(this).val()` to get the value of the selected option.

Comment: thank you very much @Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#dropdowncities").change(function () {
if ($('#dropdowncities option:selected').val() > 0)  {
    $(".filter-dot").removeClass("hide");
    $(".filter-dot").addClass("show");
} else {
    $(".filter-dot").removeClass('show');
    $(".filter-dot").addClass("hide");
}
});
```

```css
.filter-dot {
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background:red;
    border-radius:50%; 
}

.show {display:block;}

.hide {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter-dot hide"></div>

<select id="dropdowncities">
    <option value="0">Select</option>
    <option value="1">This is an option</option>
    <option value="2">This is another Option</option>
    <option value="3">This is another Option</option>
    <option value="4">This is another Option</option>
    <option value="5">This is another Option</option>
    <option value="6">This is another Option</option>
    <option value="7">This is another Option</option>
    <option value="8">This is another Option</option>
    <option value="9">This is another Option</option>
    <option value="10">This is another Option</option>
</select>
```

It's gonna work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if the value is falsy, you really want to check if the current value is not the default. You can do that by comparing the current value with the text "Select":

```js
$("#dropdowncities").change(function () {
  switch($('#dropdowncities option:selected').val()) {
    case "Select":
      $(".filter-dot").removeClass('show');
      $(".filter-dot").addClass("hide");
      break;
    default:
      $(".filter-dot").removeClass("hide");
      $(".filter-dot").addClass("show");
  }
});
```

```css
.filter-dot {
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background:red;
    border-radius:50%; 
}

.show {display:block;}

.hide {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="filter-dot hide"></div>

<select id="dropdowncities">
    <option>Select</option>
    <option>This is an option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok my bad. In my code i have this line:

```
<option>Select</option>
```

that prevent the jquery to work properly. If i change it to `<option></option>` it works perfect.

```js
$("#dropdowncities").change(function () {
if ($('#dropdowncities option:selected').val()) {
    $(".filter-dot").removeClass("hide");
    $(".filter-dot").addClass("show");
} else {
    $(".filter-dot").removeClass('show');
    $(".filter-dot").addClass("hide");
}
});
```

```css
.filter-dot {
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background:red;
    border-radius:50%; 
}

.show {display:block;}

.hide {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="filter-dot hide"></div>

<select id="dropdowncities">
    <option></option>
    <option>This is an option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You'll find my answer has an explanation for what was happening in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with minimal changes add `value=0` to your first option element and add condition to jquery function `($(this).val()!=0)` to check the value of selected option and add/remove class accordingly.

```js
$("#dropdowncities").change(function () {
if ($(this).val()!=0) {
    $(".filter-dot").removeClass("hide");
    $(".filter-dot").addClass("show");
} else {
    $(".filter-dot").removeClass('show');
    $(".filter-dot").addClass("hide");
}
});
```

```css
.filter-dot {
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background:red;
    border-radius:50%; 
}

.show {display:block;}

.hide {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="filter-dot hide"></div>

<select id="dropdowncities">
    <option value='0'>Select</option>
    <option>This is an option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
    <option>This is another Option</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

We just need to add the values to the option to find :

```
  `$("#dropdowncities").change(function ()
  {
       if($(this).val()  ==  "")
       {
           $(".filter-dot").removeClass("show");
           $(".filter-dot").addClass("hide");
       } 
       else
      {
           $(".filter-dot").removeClass('hide');
           $(".filter-dot").addClass("show");
      }
 });`

 `.filter-dot {
      width:10px;
      height:10px;
      background:red;
      border-radius:50%; 
  }

 .show {display:block;}

 .hide {display:none;}`

 `<script     src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/j query.min.js"></script>

  <div class="filter-dot hide"></div>

  <select id="dropdowncities">
         <option value="">Select</option>
         <option value="This is an option">This is an option</option>
         <option value="This is another Option">This is another option</option>
         <option value="This is another Option">This is another option</option>
    </select>'
```